# different radio button different queries

Tags: php

Please excuse my english i use translator.

Let's say i have on my website 4 radio buttons and one submit.
As nothing is selected and click submit button to display text such as "Please Choose."
Having selected the first radio button and click submit to send a query like

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `credits` = `credits` + $credits1 WHERE `username` = '$logged[username]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Having selected the second radio button and click submit to send request

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `credits` = `credits` + $credits2 WHERE `username` = '$logged[username]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

and others by that way.

```
if(isset($_POST['radio'])) {

                $choices= mysql_escape_string($_POST['choices']);

}else{
?>
<form method="post" action="">

<input type="radio" name="choices" value="1" /> Run Query 1
<input type="radio" name="choices" value="2" /> Run Query 2
<input type="radio" name="choices" value="3" /> Run Query 3

<input type="submit" class="buttonsub" name="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

this ?

Comment: what do you want to do ? what is your issue ?

Comment: Here is what I think he means: I have a form with 4 radio buttons. If the form is submitted with no button selected I want to display a warning message. If the first button is selected I want to run the first mysql query and if the second is selected run a different query, and so on.

Comment: @Благовест Тодоров, we can't write the code for you. You'll need to show us your PHP code that receives the form submit. In that code you'll detect what button value was received and execute the proper mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try code given below

```
 if(isset($_POST['choices']) && !empty($_POST['choices'])){
        if($_POST['choices'] == '1'){
             //Run query for credit1
        }elseif($_POST['choices'] == '2'){
             //Run query for credit2
        }elseif($_POST['choices'] == '3'){
             //Run query for credit3
        }elseif($_POST['choices'] == '4'){
             //Run query for credit4
        } 
}else{
     echo "Please select once choice for submit query!";
}
```

If you are running queries given above in question then you not need to put if else conditions. Just put post value in `$credit` and run query.

thanks

Comment: Thank you everything is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

give your input fields a name "

```
<input type='radio' name = ' credit1 '...>" and so forth,
```

in the php set them as a variable

```
    $radio1 = $_POST['credit1']; $radio2 = $_POST['credit2'];
```

and then make an if statement :

```
 if($radio1 == 'the value you gave your input') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET credits = 
                credits + $credits1 WHERE username    
                = '" . $logged[username] . "'");}
 elseif( $radio2 == 'other value') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET credits = 
    credits + $credits2 WHERE username
     = '" . $logged[username] . "'");}
```

hope i understood your problem and was helpful