# Filter Data with Radio Buttons

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I want to try and add two filters to my webpage.

- One filter for date and the other filter for color.
- If no filter is set then all records should be displayed.

I am trying to use if/else statements along with the name/value pairs.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  I have tried several things and this is what I have ended up with. I have also read many pages and tried using these for example but nothing seems to work for me.
[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624698/filter-a-search-with-radio-button-php-sql)[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751666/different-radio-button-different-queries)

---

**HTML / PHP**

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'cars') or die('Error connecting to MySQL Server.');

//If RadioButton Clicked Sort the Database by dateadded Asc / Desc
if(isset($_POST['dateorder'])){
        if($_POST['dateorder'] == 'dateasc'){
             //Run query for dateasc
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails ORDER BY caradded asc";
        }elseif($_POST['dateorder'] == 'datedesc'){
             //Run query for datedesc
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails ORDER BY caradded desc";
        }
}else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails ORDER BY id asc";
}

//If RadioButton Clicked Sort the Database by Color Red, Green, Blue
if(isset($_POST['color'])){
        if($_POST['color'] == 'red'){
             //Run query for red color
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails WHERE color = 'red'";
        }elseif($_POST['color'] == 'green'){
             //Run query for green color
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails WHERE color = 'green'";
        }elseif($_POST['color'] == 'blue'){
             //Run query for blue color
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails WHERE color = 'blue'";
        }
}else{
     $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails ORDER BY id asc";
}


$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error Refreshing the page: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));

//Retrieve the practice tasks from the database table
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

//start pagination
//Get the total count of rows.
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM cardetails";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

//Here we have the total row count
$rows = $row[0];

//Number of results to show per page
$page_rows = 5;

//This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

//This makes sure last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
//establish the $pagenum variable
$pagenum = 1;

//Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}

//This makes sure the page number isn't below 1 or more than our $last page
if($pagenum < 1){
    $pagenum = 1;
} else if($pagenum > $last) {
    $pagenum = $last;
}
//This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum
$limit = 'LIMIT ' . ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

//This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying the limit variable
$sql = "SELECT id, caradded, make, color FROM cardetails ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);


//$paginationCrls variable
$paginationCtrls = ' ';

//if there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /*First we check if we are on page one.  If we are then we don't need a link to
    the previous page or the first page so we do nothing.  If we aren't then we generate
    links to the first page and to the previous page.*/

    if($pagenum > 1){
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?pn=' .$previous. '">&#171; Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        //Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0) {
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?pn=' . $i .'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
//Render the target page number, but without it being a link
$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
//Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
    $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;';
    if($i >= $pagenum+4){
        break;
    }
}
//This adds the same as above only checking if if we are on the last page and then generating Next
if($pagenum != $last){
    $next = $pagenum + 1;
    $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next &#187;</a> ';
}
}
//Finish Pagination
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Basic Page Layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basicstyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerwrap">
        <div id="header">
            <p>Search / Filter Practice</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
        <div id="leftcolumn">
                <h2>Trial Filters</h2>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        <p>Filter by Date:</p> 
            <input type="radio" name="dateorder" value="dateasc"><label for="dateasc">A - Z</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="dateorder" value="datedesc"><label for="datedesc">Z - A</label><br>
            <br><hr>
        <p>Filter by Colour:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="red"><label for="red">Red</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="green"><label for="green">Green</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"><label for="blue">Blue</label>
            <br><br>
            <input name="submit" type="submit">
            <br><br>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="content">
        <p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">My Database Records</p>
<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Car Added On</th>";
echo "<th>Make</th>"; 
echo "<th>Color</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row['caradded'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['make'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['color'] ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
print '</table><br><br>';

//close connection to database
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
<p id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls;?><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="footerwrap">
        <div id="footer">
            <p>July / August 2016</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MySQL**

```
CREATE DATABASE cars;

USE cars;

CREATE TABLE cardetails(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
caradded datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
make VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
color VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

DESCRIBE cardetails;

INSERT INTO cardetails(caradded, make, color) VALUES
(NOW(), "Toyota", "Red"),
(NOW(), "VW", "Green"),
(NOW(), "Nissan", "Blue"),
(NOW(), "Toyota", "Green"),
(NOW(), "Toyota", "Green"),
(NOW(), "VW", "Blue"),
(NOW(), "VW", "Green"),
(NOW(), "Nissan", "Blue"),
(NOW(), "Nissan", "Green");

SELECT * FROM cardetails;
```

Comment: What is your specific question? What does not work?

Comment: Hi Luca, when I click on either asc or desc radio button, nothing happens, I need more code, help in figuring out.

Comment: @LucaJung updated my example, if you have any ideas.

Comment: look the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You had two opening brackets in your if-Statement. I marked it in your source code.
Hope that solved your problem.

***Edit 2:***
You always get the default SQL query when you only select one radio button for dateorder because you overwrite the dateorder query with the second if-block. You have to put the second block into a else if block. (Look Code below)
**Additional information:**
In this Strucktur there will be a bug when you select a color and date filter in common because then you always get only the date query. To avoid this bug, call all input fields with the same name

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['dateorder'])){
        if($_POST['dateorder'] == 'dateasc'){
             //Run query for dateasc
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails ORDER BY caradded asc";
        }elseif($_POST['dateorder'] == 'datedesc'){
             //Run query for datedesc
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails ORDER BY caradded desc";
        }
}else if(isset($_POST['color'])){
        if($_POST['color'] == 'red'){
             //Run query for red color
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails WHERE color = 'red'";
        }elseif($_POST['color'] == 'green'){
             //Run query for green color
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails WHERE color = 'green'";
        }elseif($_POST['color'] == 'blue'){
             //Run query for blue color
             $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails WHERE color = 'blue'";
        }
}else{
     $query = "SELECT * FROM cardetails ORDER BY id asc";
}
?>
```

***Edit:***
You don't use the updated query because you send your query before the if-Statement. After that you only send the updated query but don't save it into $result.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Date:</p>
    <input id="dateorderasc" type="radio" name="dateorder" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="dateasc"<?php if (isset($_POST['dateorder']) && $_POST['dateorder'] == 'dateasc') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label for="dateasc">Newest &rsaquo; Oldest</label>
    <br>
    <input id="dateorderdesc" type="radio" name="dateorder" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="datedesc" <?php if (isset($_POST['dateorder']) && $_POST['dateorder'] == 'datedesc') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label for="datedesc">Oldest &rsaquo; Newest</label>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
//connect
include ("db.connect.php");

//Retrieve the tasks from the database table
$query = "SELECT * FROM tasks";

//If RadioButton Clicked Sort the Database by Date Asc / Desc
if(isset($_POST['dateorder']) && !empty($_POST['dateorder'])){
    if ($_POST['dateorder'] == 'dateasc'){                  //HERE
        $query .= " ORDER BY date ASC";
    }
    if ($_POST['dateorder'] == 'datedesc'){
        $query .= " ORDER BY date DESC";
    }
}
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error Refreshing the page: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
include("dbresults.php");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks again, updated, but nothing. I will play around with it a bit more and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: The query is now updated in my demo. Are you sure that your query correct is?

Comment: I updated my answer, which var do you use to display the result? I pushed the $result down in order to use the updated $query. Does this work?

Comment: Sure it was, will have to leave for now, thanks for your help. A break might help me see the obvious mistake later ;-)